# Question about elementary limits

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\;f(x)\;$ is a continuous function, and that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2017}\big(x+f(x)\big)=2018$$

I want to know if $\;y=2017\;$ intersects the graph of function $\;y=\left(2018x^2-x^3\right)f(x)\;$ multiple times.

Is it correct to say that $\;f(x)=2018-x\;$, since if we separate the limit into two limits, we get
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2017}\big(x+f(x)\big)=\lim_{x\rightarrow2017}x+\lim_{x\rightarrow2017}f(x)=2018\Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow 2017}f(x)=1,$$

and because of this the limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow n}x=n$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You can say that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2017}f(x)=1.$ And $2018-x$ verifies that condition but it is not the unique function doing it.

Comment: @mfl So essentially that would be the incorrect way to go about finding how many times the function intersects y=2017? Or is it appropriate to use ANY real function that verifies that condition in this way? Or could I say $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2017}2017=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2017}(2018x^2-x^3)\lim_{x\rightarrow 2017}f(x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, $\lim_{x\to2017}f(x)=1$ and since $f$ is continuous, $f(2017)=1$. This is all we can say about $f$ which is not enough information to determine the number of intersection points or what $f$ actually is. $f(x)=2018-x$ is only one possibility and there's infinitely many.

However, we can guarantee at least $2$ intersection points. If you let $g(x)=(2018x^2-x^3)f(x)$, then $g(0)=0, g(2017)=2017^2$, and $g(2018)=0$. $g$ is continuous (since $f$ is continuous) and by the Intermediate Value Theorem there are numbers $a\in(0,2017)$ and $b\in(2017,2018)$ such that $g(a)=2017, g(b)=2017$. So $2$ intersection points are $(a,2017)$ and $(b,2017)$.

An example with exactly $2$ intersection points is $f(x)=x/2017$. $f(x)=1$ would give you exactly $3$ intersection points. And there's an example with infinitely many intersection points.

Comment: I completely understand now. This makes perfect sense. Thank you. I see now that continuity is vital in this reasoning.